# Port forwarding using adb shell commands

Tags: android, linux, adb, port

I want to connect with my linux pc through ssh to my linux device which is connected via USB to my android device(Only using adb shell commands)

For now I'm doing it using two apps which is installed on my android device:
1. Network IP scanner, which gives me the IP of the target device.
2. FwdPortForwardingApp (https://github.com/elixsr/FwdPortForwardingApp)

With that App I perform port forwarding using BOTH udp and tcp protocols from wlan0 on port 2222 to the target IP I got from the network IP scanner on port 22.

I want to do it using only adb shell commands, how can I do it?

Tried adb forward tcp:2222 tcp:22 and adb reverse tcp:2222 tcp:22 which didn't help

Expected to perform ssh using port 2222 directly to my device using only adb shell commands (Cause I want to create a script which will perform all the commands together without using the android device)